# How do I prevent a GPU lockup?

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, gpu

I recently installed Ubuntu on an old Dell XPS 410. I was able to go through the install process without any problems,  save the fact that I had no hardware to connect to the Internet. When I try to boot up the computer, it will take me to the Ubuntu login screen. Once I log in, the GPU will lock up. The screen will freeze, and sometimes I was able to see an error message pop up and blink two or three times. Then, the desktop interface will either freeze completely, or fade to a command line, which reads "GPU lockup - switching to software fbcon", where it will then "fail to idle channel".

If you are able to help in any way, it would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: I still haven't managed to connect to the internet, however, I can boot up to a desktop environment if I boot from safe mode.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2` terminal command and specify your Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

Install the NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver for the Dell XPS 410 Desktop. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-173 nvidia-settings  
sudo reboot
```

Comment: The problem is that it won't install on 14.04.2.

Comment: nvidia-173 is in the Ubuntu Software Center for Ubuntu 14.04 and it's also in the latest Ubuntu 14.04 package search results online and you say that it won't install on Ubuntu 14.04.2. This is very confusing because if it can't be installed, then nvidia-173 has no business being in the Ubuntu repositories. I think I'm going to leave my answer the way it is in case you are reporting an isolated incident that nvidia-173 won't install on 14.04.2. I've never had any experience in Ubuntu that a package from the Ubuntu Software Center couldn't be installed.

Comment: This is a good point. nvidia-173 will install to 14.04. But 14.04.2 came out with new version of xorg stack and oops, nvidia-173 does not install. 14.04 and 14.04.2 share same repositories. But I know how to fix it. Your answer is partially correct, but it won't work, if OP has 14.04.2.

Comment: Good point. Now I know that the Ubuntu Software Center is not infallible.

Comment: Pilot, the outcome for the command (lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2) is "VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G72 [GeForce 7300 LE] (rev a1)"